# How to disable developerprofile file another mac

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

I exported my developerprofile via preferences->accounts->export account. Then I set up the developer profile on another Mac but now I don't know how to disable that developerprofile on the new mac by using the old mac .How can I managed to do it?

Comment: Are you using the same Apple iD in both mac?

Comment: You should revoke the profile directly from the provisioning portal

Comment: Is a private account or company account? If is a private account you can develop only in one mac. In this case you shoul revoke the certificate, refresh your xcode in old mac, then create a new certificate and install it on the new mac. I hope this can help you

Comment: Couldn't get it you mean you exported profile from a mac lets say A then setup on mac B now you want to disable on mac A from which you exported. right?

Comment: My exported developer file has both personal and company account.Actually, i want to disable it on the another mac. Another mac is used by another person. I can not reach to that person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue and wanted to share with you. Firstly, i have changed the passwords of both my personal and company account. Then, I deleted my account from preferences -> accounts. I have logged into my accounts with my new password. When I try to use my old exported developer profile on the new another mac, it give an error. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to that system what you can do is revoked you certificate and make new profile on your system. Other person can use it unless it expired or he try to use account online rather then choosing the local profile. 
If you have access you can simply delete profile and certificate and logout from preferences.

Comment: Do my active applications get effected if I revoke the active certificates and       should I build it again after this. Is there any way to do this without revoking the certificates?

Comment: No application will be affected .

Comment: There is no way even after you revoke other user can use unless expired or he try to use account online . Because when profile is active he can choose the option of "Use local signing asset".